# Compare largest root of two polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

For $1\leq a, a+1<b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ let

- $f:=f(a,b):=\sum_{i=2}^{b-a}i,$
- $g:=g(a,b):=f(a,b)+a+b+1$
- $h:=h(a,b):=f(a,b)-(b-a-1)$

and consider the polynomial
$$
p(t):=t^g-\left(\sum_{i=h}^f t^i\right).
$$

I would like to show that the largest (in absolute value) root of $p(t)$ is smaller than the largest (in absolute value) root of the polynomial
$$
q(t):=t^{a+b+1}-t^{a+b}-1.
$$

---

We can factor out $t^h$, i.e. 
$$
p(t)=t^h\cdot\left(t^{g-h}-\sum_{i=1}^{b-a-1}t^i -1\right),
$$
so
$$
p(t)=0\Leftrightarrow t^h=0\quad\text{ or }\quad t^{g-h}-\sum_{i=1}^{b-a-1}t^i-1=0
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this proof, we only need that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ with $a<b$.  We have
$$p(t)=t^{\frac{(b-a-1)(b-a-2)}{2}}\left(t^{2b}-\sum_{k=0}^{b-a-1}\,t^k\right)\,.$$
Observe that each of the two polynomials $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ has a unique positive real root (using Descartes's Rule of Signs, or something similar---there are a multitude of ways to show this simple result).

Write $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the positive real roots of $p(t)$ and $q(t)$, respectively.  Using Rouché's Theorem, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $p(t)$ and $q(t)$, respectively, with the largest moduli amongst all (real or complex) roots. (Rouché's Theorem is not necessary here; this result can be proven via the Triangle Inequality for complex numbers.)

> Let $B(r,z) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ denote the open ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  To use Rouché's Theorem for $p$, consider the disc $B(\alpha+\epsilon,0)$, where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary.  At the boundary, $$\big|z^{2b}\big|>\left|-\sum_{k=0}^{b-a-1}\,z^k\right|$$ for all $z\in \partial B(\alpha+\epsilon,0)$, whence the polynomial $p(t)$ has the same number of roots in $B(\alpha+\epsilon,0)$ as the polynomial $t^{2b}$, which is $2b$.  That is, all roots of $p(t)$ are in $\bigcap\limits_{\epsilon>0}\,B(\alpha+\epsilon,0)$, which is the same as the closed ball $\bar{B}(\alpha,0)$. 
>  For $q$, you can do something similar, but I am using the Triangle Inequality to deal with it now.  Note that $\big|q(z)\big|\geq q\big(|z|\big)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ by the Triangle Inequality.  If $z$ is a complex number such that $|z|>\beta$, we get $$\big|q(z)\big|\geq q\big(|z|\big)>0\,.$$  Thus, all roots of $q$ are in the closed ball $\bar{B}(\beta,0)$.

If $b=a+1$, then clearly $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$ (because $q(1)<0$).  From now on, suppose that $b>a+1$, which means $\alpha>1$ and $\beta>1$ (noting that $p(1)<0$ and $q(1)<0$).

Suppose contrary that $\alpha\geq \beta$.  Since $\beta^{a+b}(\beta-1)=q(\beta)+1=1$, we obtain
$$\alpha^{a+b}\left(\alpha-1\right)\geq \beta^{a+b}\left(\beta-1\right)=1\,.$$
Now, since $p(\alpha)=0$ and $\alpha\neq 0$, we get that
$$\alpha^{2b}=\sum_{k=0}^{b-a-1}\,\alpha^k=\frac{\alpha^{b-a}-1}{\alpha-1}\,.$$
That is,
$$1\leq \alpha^{a+b}(\alpha-1)=\frac{\alpha^{b-a}-1}{\alpha^{b-a}}<1\,,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: I did not understand yet how to see that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots with the largest magnitude.

Comment: @Rhjg  See the hidden box for an elaboration.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great

Comment: In the last inequality, isn't it $1\leqslant \alpha^{a+b}(\alpha-1)=\frac{\alpha^{2b}-\alpha^{a+b}}{\alpha^{2b}}<1$?

Comment: Hmm?  What's the difference?   $$\frac{\alpha^{2b}-\alpha^{a+b}}{\alpha^{2b}}=\frac{\alpha^{b-a}-1}{\alpha^{b-a}}\,.$$

Answer (score -1):

Part of the claim (namely about the maximal positive root of $p$) follows by straightforward computation:

Note that 
$$\tag1 q(t)=(t-1)t^{a+b}-1$$
As $q(1)=-1$ and $q(t)\to+\infty$ as $t\to+\infty$, there is clearly a root of $q$ outside $[-1,1]$, i.e., we need only consider $|t|>1$.

Let $t_\min$, $t_\max$ be the smallest and largest root of $q$, respectively. As  seen above, $t_\max>1$ and $q(t)>0$ for $t>t_\max$.
Using the formula for geometric series, we verify
$$\tag2\frac{ p(t)}{t^{f+1}}=\frac{q(t)}{t-1}+\frac{t^{b-1}}{t-1}$$
Then using $q(t)\ge 0$ for $t\ge t_\max>1$, it follows from $(2)$ that $p(t)>0$ for all $t\ge t_\max$.
In particular,

> The maximal root of $p$ is strictly smaller than the maximal root of $q$.

Comment: How do you get (2)?